# interfaciing with a 5mp csi camera

Tags: i2c, camera, interface

I'm trying to interface an intel edison board with a 5mp mipi camera (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13249)
The camera uses an OV5640 imaging sensor, and is used with a pcduino v3. It interfaces with the pcduino via csi interface. I'm trying to have the intel edison interface with the camera. Is it possible to interface it with I2C with the sda and scl pins from the camera module? Or do I have to use csi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the OV5640 datasheet in front of me but I can assure you won't be getting video over I2C.  Most sensors use I2C or SPI sometimes just to configure the sensor's many, many settings registers.   This control interface is also often used by the ISP (image signal processing) portion of the design, that attempts to make a pretty picture out of what you get back from the camera by adjusting all of those settings.

So short answer is I2C is for config the other interface is for image data which will be coming at a much higher rate.